# Overflow & Underflow

Tags: javascript, class, stack

I am trying to figure out the solution but I can't find it. I need a function that throws an error when maximum call stack is reached and throws an error when minimum call stack is reached.

```
class Stack {
    constructor() {
        this.items = [];`Please Help me with this...`
    }
    push(item) {
        this.items.push(item)
    }
    pop() {
        const popped = this.items.pop();
        if (this.items == null) {
            throw new Error("Underflow");
        }
        return popped;
    }
    isEmpty() {
        
    }
    peek() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean maximum?

Comment: yes I mean Maximum call stack...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about modifying your functions?

`push` and `pop` should throw an error if `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` or `<= 0` is reached.

```js
class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }
  push(item) {
    if (this.items.length >= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) {
      throw new Error("Maximum call stack reached");
    }
    this.items.push(item)
  }
  pop() {
    if (this.items.length <= 0) {
      throw new Error("Minimum call stack reached");
    }
    return this.items.pop();
  }
  isEmpty() {
    return this.items.length === 0;
  }
  peek() {
    return this.items[this.items.length - 1];
  }
}
```

Comment: It says that MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is not defined... Is there any replacement for that? Thanks for helping !

Comment: How about `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`?

Comment: Doesn't Work @sm3sher Any replacement like Ex: <= 0 something like that??

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The function should throw an error but it doesn't pass that test case..? How do I do that???

Comment: How does your test case look like? You might need to replace `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` with a number that fits your needs.